# When to use ebs_block_device?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create an EC2 instance with Terraform. This instance should have some EBS.

In the documentation I read that Terraform provides two ways to create an EBS:

- `ebs_block_device`
- `aws_ebs_volume` with `aws_volume_attachment`

I want to know, when should I use `ebs_block_device`?

**Documentation**

Unfortunately the documentation isn't that clear (at least for me) about:

- When to use `ebs_block_device`?
- How is the exact actual behavior?

See [Resource: aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance):

> `ebs_block_device` - (Optional) One or more configuration blocks with additional EBS block devices to attach to the instance. Block device configurations only apply on resource creation. See Block Devices below for details on attributes and drift detection. When accessing this as an attribute reference, it is a set of objects.

and

> Currently, changes to the `ebs_block_device` configuration of existing resources cannot be automatically detected by Terraform. To manage changes and attachments of an EBS block to an instance, use the `aws_ebs_volume` and `aws_volume_attachment` resources instead. If you use `ebs_block_device` on an `aws_instance`, Terraform will assume management over the full set of non-root EBS block devices for the instance, treating additional block devices as drift. For this reason, `ebs_block_device` cannot be mixed with external `aws_ebs_volume` and `aws_volume_attachment` resources for a given instance.

**Research**

I read:

- [No change when modifying aws_instance.ebs_block_device.volume_size](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4029), which says that Terraform doesn't show any changes with `plan`/`apply` and doesn't change anything in AWS, although changes were made..
- [AWS "ebs_block_device.0.volume_id": this field cannot be set](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/issues/130), which says that Terraform shows an error while running `plan`.
- [Ebs_block_device forcing replacement every terraform apply](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/ebs-block-device-forcing-replacement-every-terraform-apply/23476), which says that Terraform replaces all EBS.
- [aws_instance dynamic ebs_block_device forces replacement](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13118), which says that Terraform replaces all EBS, although no changes were made.
- [adding ebs_block_device to existing aws_instance forces unneccessary replacement](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21396), which says that Terraform replaces the whole EC2 instance with all EBS.
- [aws_instance dynamic ebs_block_device forces replacement](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20305), which says that Terraform replaces the whole EC2 instance with all EBS, although no changes were made.

I know that the issues are about different versions of Terraform and Terraform AWS provider and some issues are already fixed, but what is the actual intended behavoir?

In almost all issues the workaround/recommendation is to use `aws_ebs_volume` with `aws_volume_attachment` instead of `ebs_block_device`.

**Question**

When should I use `ebs_block_device`? What is the use case for this feature?

Comment: Basically the difference is whether you want the CRUD operations for the EBS volume tied to the EC2 instance (`ebs_block_device`), or whether they should be treated independently (`aws_ebs_volume`). In general you would prefer the latter as instances are usually more ephemeral than storage.

Answer (score 7):

I strongly suggest using only resource `aws_ebs_volume`. When creating an instance, the root block will be created automatically. For extra EBS storage, you will want Terraform to manage them independently.
Why?

Basically you have 2 choices to create an instance with 1 extra disk:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami                  = "ami-xxxx"
  instance_type        = "t4g.micro"
  #... other arguments ...

  ebs_block_device {
    volume_size = 10
    volume_type = "gp3"
    #... other arguments ...
  }
}
```

OR

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami                  = "ami-xxxx"
  instance_type        = "t4g.micro"
  #... other arguments ...
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "volume" {
  size = 10
  type = "gp3"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "attachment" {
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.volume.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.instance.id
  device_name = "/dev/sdb"
}
```

The first method is more compact, creates fewer Terraform resource and makes `terraform import` easier. But if you need to recreate your instance what will happen? Terraform will remove the instance, and redeploy it from scratch with **new** volumes. If you use the argument `delete_on_termination` to false, the volumes will still exist but they won't be attached to your instance.

In the contrary, when using a dedicated resource, the instance recreation will recreate the attachements (because the instance id changes) and then, reattach your existing volumes to your instance, which is what we need 90% of the time.

Also, if at some point you need to manipulate your volume in the Terraform state (`terraform state` commands), it will be much easier to do it on the individual resource `aws_ebs_volume`.

Finally, at some point in your Terraform journey, you will want to industrialize your code by adding loops, variables and so on. A common use case is to make the number of volumes variables: you provide a list of volumes and Terraform create 1, 2 or 10 volumes according to this list.
And for this you have also have 2 options :

```
variable "my_volume" { map(any) }
my_volume = {
  "/dev/sdb": {
    "size": 10
    "type": "gp3"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami                  = "ami-xxxx"
  instance_type        = "t4g.micro"
  #... other arguments ...

  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = var.my_volumes
    content {
      volume_size = ebs_block_device.value["size"]
      volume_type = ebs_block_device.value["type"]
      #... other arguments ...
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami                  = "ami-xxxx"
  instance_type        = "t4g.micro"
  #... other arguments ...
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "volume" {
  for_each = var.
  size = 10
  type = "gp3"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "attachment" {
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.volume.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.instance.id
  device_name = "/dev/sdb"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*When should I use ebs_block_device?*

When you need another volume other than the root volume because

> Unlike the data stored on a local instance store (which persists only
> as long as that instance is alive), data stored on an Amazon EBS
> volume can persist independently of the life of the instance.

When you launch an instance, the root device volume contains the image used to boot the instance.

> Instances that use Amazon EBS for the root device automatically have
> an Amazon EBS volume attached. When you launch an Amazon EBS-backed
> instance, we create an Amazon EBS volume for each Amazon EBS snapshot
> referenced by the AMI you use

[image]

Here's an example of an EC2 with additional EBS volume.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size = 8
    volume_type = "gp3"
    throughput = 125
    delete_on_termination = false
  }
}
```

**Note**: `delete_on_termination` for `root_block_device` is set to `true` by default.

You can read more on AWS block device mapping [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html).

---

EDIT:

`aws_volume_attachment` is used when you want to attach *an existing* EBS volume to an EC2 instance. It helps to manage the relationship between the volume and the instance, and ensure that the volume is attached to the desired instance in the desired state.

Here's an example usage:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.example.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.web.id
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami               = "ami-21f78e11"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  instance_type     = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "example" {
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  size              = 1
}
```

and the `ebs_block_device` is used when you want to create a *new* EBS volume and attach it to an EC2 instance at the same time as the instance is being created.

NOTE:

> If you use `ebs_block_device` on an `aws_instance`, Terraform will assume
> management over the full set of non-root EBS block devices for the
> instance, and treats additional block devices as drift. For this
> reason, `ebs_block_device` cannot be mixed with external `aws_ebs_volume` + `aws_volume_attachment` resources for a given instance.

[Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/volume_attachment)

Comment: Most AMIs are no longer instance-store and have EBS-backed root volumes. Instance-store-backed AMIs are now only available on older generations (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html).